# comparar una fecha string con sysdate o current_date

Tags: sql, oracle, select, date

tengo un problema al hacer un select que me muestre datos siempre y cuando la fecha final sea mayor a la actual("en otras palabras que este vigente"),
el problema es que el select me muestras datos que ya no estan vigentes o que experiraron.
este es el select que uso:

```
select * from UTIC.UZGTFORMULARIOS where UZGTFORMULARIOS_FECHA_FIN >= TO_CHAR(sysdate,'DD/MM/RRRR')
```

el campo UZGTFORMULARIOS_FECHA_FIN es tipo varchar y la fecha se guarda con el siguiente formato DD/MM/RRRR

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
como veran me muestras fechas del mes que pasó y el select deberia mostrar solo fechas de hoy para adelante.
alguna recomendacion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estás comparando cadenas con cadenas (CHAR)... Eso solo hará una comparación alfabéticamente (alfanuméricamente???), pero una fecha no se puede comparar así correctamente.

Deberías usar

```
TO_DATE(UZGTFORMULARIOS_FECHA_FIN) >= TRUNC(sysdate)
```

En lugar de pasar a CHAR el sysdate, lo dejas como su tipo, que es DATE, y lo comparas con la otra columna, luego de pasarla a DATE.

El TRUNC es opcional, sirve para que solo tenga en cuenta la fecha, no la hora.

Comment: intenté como me recomendaste con el siguiente select:                                    select * from UTIC.UZGTFORMULARIOS where TO_DATE(UZGTFORMULARIOS_FECHA_FIN) >= TRUNC(sysdate)
  pero me sale el siguiente error:                                                                          ORA-01861: el literal no coincide con la cadena de formato

Comment: Lo que está en la otra respuesta es correcto. Normalmente yo tengo por default la mascara en `'dd/mm/yyyy'`, mala mía. Si eso tampoco funciona, es probable que tengas al menos un registro que NO cumple con este formato de fecha, y lo(s) deberías corregir

Answer (score 0):

¿Está seguro de la columna UZGTFORMULARIOS_FECHA_FI es de tipo VARCHAR2?

Si es así tiene que usar el segundo parámetro de la función **TO_DATE** para indicar como es el string de fecha.
Cuando no se usa el segundo parámetro entonces Oracle usa el formato que esté definido para la sesión con la cual se conectó y que depende de la variable de ambiente NLS_LANG.

```
TO_DATE(UZGTFORMULARIOS_FECHA_FIN,'dd/mm/yyyy') >= TRUNC(sysdate)
```